# Embedding OrientDB 2.2.33 as Karaf 4.1.4 feature

Tags: osgi, orientdb, apache-karaf

I'm using 2.2.33 OrientDb under Karaf 4.1.4. The Karaf feature with bundle activator is done:

```
<repository>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/1.2.1/xml/features</repository>

<feature name="orientdb-server" description="OrientDB NoSQL Database" version="${orientdb.version}">
    <bundle>mvn:com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-core/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-tools/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-client/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-server/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-distributed/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.0.0</bundle>
</feature>
```

But by feature installation, I've got a dependency error as shown below.

> Failed to install feature orientdb-server due to org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException : Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=orientdb-server; type=karaf.feature; version="[2.2.33,2.2.33]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=orientdb-server)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=2.2.33)(version<=2.2.33))" [caused by: Unable to resolve orientdb-server/2.2.33: missing requirement [orientdb-server/2.2.33] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=com.orientechnologies.orientdb-tools; type=osgi.bundle; version="[2.2.33,2.2.33]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve com.orientechnologies.orientdb-tools/2.2.33: missing requirement [com.orientechnologies.orientdb-tools/2.2.33] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=com.orientechnologies.common.collection)" [caused by: Unable to resolve com.orientechnologies.orientdb-core/2.2.33: missing requirement [com.orientechnologies.orientdb-core/2.2.33] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=javax.annotation.meta)"]]]

I found the `javax.annotation.meta` in Vaadin, GWT and servlet-api.
First two are frontend parts and the only remaining candidate wasthe servlet-api because of its embedded Studion UI.

But adding the following dependency doesn't help as well.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It works now

```
272 │ Active      │  80 │ 1.4.2              │ ConcurrentLinkedHashMap
273 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.2.33             │ OrientDB Client
274 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.2.33             │ OrientDB Core
275 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.2.33             │ OrientDB JDBC Driver
276 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.2.33             │ OrientDB Server
277 │ Active      │  80 │ 2.2.33             │ OrientDB Tools
278 │ Active      │  80 │ 3.0.1              │ FindBugs-jsr305
```

the corresponding feature is:

```
<repository>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/1.2.1/xml/features</repository>

<feature name="orientdb-embedded" description="OrientDB NoSQL Database" version="${orientdb.version}">
    <bundle>mvn:com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-core/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-server/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-client/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-tools/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.orientechnologies/orientdb-jdbc/${orientdb.version}</bundle>
</feature>
```